Is there any help with the deforming weight error rig?
How do I fix this error? I had a deforming weight error rig problem.
I made the painting weight and then symmetry both arms.

then The derform looks terrible when it's in pose mode.

how do I solve this problem? please make sure to add a picture or video As an example. 

The parenting with Automatic Weights didn't work correctly because your faces were inverted (image), to fix that go in Edit mode, select all and recalculate the normals (ShiftN):

